# Doubt about Bezier handle type switching

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

Have you ever encountered that the handle type of Bezier vertices cannot be changed from time to time?

To ensure that the Bezier handle type changes, you need to do one of two things:

(1) Use Box Select to drag to a large area outside the Bezier handle.

(2) Single-click on the area outside the Bezier spline before dragging around the vertices.

If it's as designed, it's a bit annoying.

What do you think about this?

Please refer to the image for details.

NOTE:

These are not the case if you select one vertex directly.

Only when you select vertices using "Box Select".

With the view that this issue is "working as designed",
Not considered a bug.

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the design. If you select only one handle of the control point, you can set only this handle to a particular type. If you select the control point, it automatically selects both its handles, no need for box select. And if you change the CP's interpolation type, both its handles change accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
In the case of one vertex, you're right.

I've shown it at one vertex for simplicity.
The actual work is dragging many vertices, right?
At that time, I think that there will be a problem with the behavior of the vertices of the edge.

Comment: I'm still not sure what's exactly your problem but you can hide handles and show only Control Points using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpQ3L.png) requires at least v2.92 or 2.93 can't remember

Comment: I'm not asking for an answer in this matter.

Please refer to the image.
Do not perform (No. 3 "Full drag of handle")
 and (No. 7 "single click"),
 and proceed to the next process.
Maybe you won't get a circle immediately.
Why is that?
I want you to consider the reason.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand the question. Could you rephrase it in one sentence eg "I do not understand why, when I perform x, y happens" ? FYI this is not a site for discussing design decisions.

Comment: Wasn't this a site for discussing design decisions? Sincerest apologies.
One last thing I want to tell you.

Common Bezier spline tools are
Selecting a Bezier handle does not hold it.
I'm used to this so I'm confused in the Blender.

Blender is special and holds the Bezier handle selection.
I think the hold of Bezier handle selection is beneficial,
I think it would be nice if I could choose to hold or not hold the Bezier handle selection.

Thank you and Good night.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what I understood.

To make sure change the handle type of Blender Bezier spline,
It turned out that "it is necessary to make everything selected, including not only the vertices but also the Bezier handles."

Blender's architecture is special,
The Bezier handle holds the "selected" and "unselected" states.

For beginners, the "Hold select and deselection of Bezier handles" function should be "disabled".
In other words, it does not create the "selected" and "non-selected" states of the Bezier handle.

I think that the function of "holding the selection and deselection of the Bezier handle" is beneficial in its own way.
In the preferences, I think it would be nice to be able to select "enabled" or "disabled" for that function.

Common Bezier spline tools do not have the ability to "hold selection and deselection of Bezier handles".

Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop, Blender Add-on Bezier Utility,
I'm used to these behaviors, so I'm very confused by the operation of the built-in blender Bezier.